# Fetch relations from ManyToMany Field using Annotation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I have my database [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koJd0.png) Where I have 2 users connected to one instance of `ChatRoomParticipants` with a ManyToManyField.

I'm trying to get list of related users from a ManyToMany Relation Field from `ChatRoomParticipants` where I don't want to show the currently authenticated user in the list with other fields i.e `room` present in the model.

Considering user `f4253fbd90d1471fb54180813b51d610` is currently logged in and is related to all `ChatRooms` via `ChatRoomParticipants` model.

Things I've tried but couldn't get the desired output

```
chatrooms = list(ChatRoomParticipants.objects.filter(user=user).values_list('user__chatroom_users__user__username', 'room').distinct())

#####
chatrooms =  ChatRoomParticipants.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(user!=User(user))

####
chatrooms = Chatrooms.objects.filter(user=user)
rooms = chatrooms.values('user__chatroom_users__user__username').distinct().exclude(user__chatroom_users__user__username=user)
```

I want an output like

```
[
    {
        'user': '872952bb6c344e50b6fd7053dfa583de'
        'room': 1
    },
    {
        'user': '99ea24b12b8c400689702b4f25ea0f40'
        'room': 2
    },
    {
        'user': 'eecd66e748744b96bde07dd37d0b83b3'
        'room': 3
    },
]
```

models.py

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_message = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)
    last_sent_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Messages(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content


class ChatRoomParticipants(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='chatroom_users')
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the database design is wrong. Especially, the `user` field in the `ChatRoomParticipants` model is defined as `ManyToManyField` but I think it should be just as `ForeignKey` because there needs to be the M2M relationship between `User` and `ChatRoom`, not between `User` and `ChatRoomParticipants`.

```
class ChatRoomParticipants(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='chatroom_users', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then the filter function should work.

First you need to get the list of rooms that the current authenticated user is in:

```
room_ids = list(ChatRoomParticipants.objects.filter(user=user).values_list('room__id', flat=True))
```

And you get the roommates:

```
participants = ChatRoomParticipants.objects.exclude(user__id = user.id).filter(room__id__in = room_ids)
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I had it as ForeignKey before but later changed it to m2m field so it would be easier to get the following output for the query. However that didn't work out either.

Comment: I added the django ORM query to get what you want. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I've tried this and I could do the thing with ```users = chatrooms.objects.all()``` after filtering out the rooms. But the thing I'm stuck with is getting everything in 1 list and not 2 separate lists.

Comment: I could still combine the 2 queries and work in that way which would save me days of work, was just curious if there's an django ORM way to do all this easier and faster.

Comment: Okay I understand. Then the original database design is completely wrong. I'll change my answer.

Comment: ```participants = list(ChatRoomParticipants.objects.exclude(user__user_uid = user.user_uid).filter(room__id__in = room_ids).values('user__username', 'room__name'))```
doing something like this worked for me, thanks. Thumbs up.

Comment: Okay, but I think the `ChatRoomParticipants` model isn't even necessary. You can remove that model and just add the `users` field in the `ChatRoom` model like `users=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'chatrooms')`

Comment: And then the queryset `rooms = ChatRoom.objects.filter(users=user)` will find the list of rooms that the current authenticated user is in.

Comment: And from each room of `rooms`, you can get the roommates by using `room.users`.

Comment: Doing that creates a weird relation between users and ChatRooms which are not even linked together while querying. Also the reason I've added this to make it more scalable just in case.

Comment: I don't think so. I once used that design. And it works great without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to keep your DB design then check the bellow link for query reference

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the query from the User model.

```
from django.db.models import F

User.objects.exclude(
    username=user
).annotate(
    room=F(
        'chatroomparticipants__room'
    )
).filter(room__isnull=False)
```

Also the `!=` in your annotation you should consider look at the Q class
[example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects),

With that you can do this negation.

```
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(
    ~Q(username=user)
)
```